# Callback function missing scope for required data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I have a issue with a callback function's variable losing its scope

.
I have the following 2 objects in an array(simplified down to show the problem)

```js
const search = [{socket: new WebSocket('ws://live.trade/123')}, 
                {socket: new WebSocket('ws://live.trade/xyz')}];
```

I then do a forEach on them in an attempt to log the sockets url once the socket is open.

```js
search.forEach(function(element){
    element.socket.on('open', function open() {
      console.log(element.socket.url);
    });
});
```

```
*actual output*
ws://live.trade/xyz
ws://live.trade/xyz

*expected*
ws://live.trade/123
ws://live.trade/xyz
```

I feel like the reason is that when the function open() runs element is not in scope and it just uses whatever was last there(being the ws://live.trade/xyz).
Is this correct? And finally what would be the way to go about fixing this? The real use for this is when the socket is opened I need to send version data to the server via the socket that called it... Im going to have many sockets in reality and dont want to write a "socket.on('open'...)" for each individual one.

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You are correct, `element.socket.url` will show you its last value. I think you would need to use `this` keyword. Not familiar with sockets much, but something like `this.url` probably?

Comment: *"Is this correct?"* No. JavaScript has lexical scope.  Which library are you using? I assume you are using one because native `WebSocket` instances don't have an `on` method.

Comment: I am using "ws: a NodeJS websocket library" https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback (*i.e. in socket.on()*) uses the `element` variable of the `forEach()`. From your actual result, it could mean that:

#### 1. Scope issue

The variable could be "*overriden*" over the iterations because of javascript/node scope mechanism, it is not the case with the code you gave but it is a common issue working with scopes inside loops.

in this case you would have to do :

```
search.forEach(function(element){
    element.socket.on('open', function(){
      console.log(this.socket.url);
    }.bind(element));
});
```

Explanation:

- `bind()` passes its first argument (the *element* variable in this case) to the anonymous function as `this` inside it.
- Inside your callback function, `this.socket` is equivalent to `element.socket` at the appropriate iteration

**[UPDATE]** after pointed out by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling), forEach() provides a scope for each element.

See [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more details.

#### 2. Dependency issue

If it is not a scope issue, it could mean that the library you are using does not work as expected. Maybe, try to log `element` inside the forEach() to check if the *WebSocket* objects are what you expect.

**edit**

- For further reading on node/js loops and reference: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)
- For node/js closures in general: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: *"this variable is overriden over the iterations because of javascript/node scope mechanism."* That's incorrect. Each function call has its own scope. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/eeqbgmh9/.

Comment: You are right ! I will edit my answer not to be so "imperative". I answered without trying out from my experience that is to be improved in this case .. I'm new to stackoverflow, do I have to delete or edit my answer ?

Comment: Bind the element object to the inner function did the trick! I will have do some more reading on the bind function for a better understanding! Thanks soo much for the help and also thanks to @FelixKling

Comment: @BrentAureli: While it may work, it's not possible that the code in your question has this problem, unless `WebSocket` is broken (but the code on GH looks fine) or *you* are somehow changing the objects in the array. Lets try something simpler. What if you did this: `search.forEach(function(element){ var socket = element.socket; socket.on('open', function open() { console.log(socket.url); }); });`

Comment: Editing your answer to remove the incorrect statements would be a start. You can still keep your solution as possible workaround.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe you are correct. That code also works. Which doesn't make sense, I believe you are correct that in my attempt to simplify the question on GH i may have removed some critical type in which I may have adjusted the object. During the refactoring with bind I must have fixed it incidentally. Its likely I should remove this question, as it was probably my fault originally though the answers did assist in resolving it. Thanks!